# ReactJS - Updating parent state when child state is changed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I apologize for the lack of working code, but I'm not sure how to go about doing this, so non-working code it is.  I am looking to update the this.state.count in the App class when the state of a ToggleBox is altered.  I'm sure this has been asked before, thanks in advance.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ToggleBox from '../components/ToggleBox';
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
      total : 60,
      count: 0
    };
  }
  getToggles() {
      let toggles = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < this.state.count; i++) {
        toggles.push(<ToggleBox checked={false} key={i} />);
      }
    return toggles;
  }

  render() {
    let toggles = this.getToggles();
    return (
      <div className="App">
        {{this.state.count}} - {{this.state.total}}
        <div className="container-toggle-box">
            {toggles}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

...and the component:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
class ToggleBox extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      active = this.props.checked
    };
    this.handleClick= this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }
  handleClick() {
    this.setState({active: (this.state.active) ? false : true}
  }
  render() {
    let mark = (this.state.active) ? 'x' : 'o'
      return (
        <span>
          {mark}
        </span>
      );
  }
}

export default ToggleBox;
```

Comment: you're just rendering the component there, you want to change some state with an onClick event on the mark? Set that prop and pass in the function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass `ToggleBox` a function that updates the count.

For example:

```
toggles.push(<ToggleBox
    checked={false} 
    key={i}
    incrementCount={() => this.setState({count: this.state.count + 1})}
/>);
```

Then you just call that method in your child component:

```
handleClick() {
    this.setState({active: (this.state.active) ? false : true};
    this.props.incrementCount();
}
```

This pattern is often referred to as "Flux" (or, to be more accurate, it's a piece of the overall Flux pattern), and it's a core part of how React was designed to be used.  By passing the function in in this way your child component doesn't have to know anything about how count works or how it's incremented.  This makes things easy for the child, but more importantly it makes it a lot easier when you want to change how the count works, because there's only a single place (the parent component) which controls it.

Comment: Perfect, thank you.  Sometimes I overthink things, and forgot about passing in a function as a prop.

Comment: What if I the state was mass togglable from the parent component?  I have been trying to use componentDidUpdate to run this.props.incrementCount(-1); but tit only runs once instead of for each toggle box.

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly then the state should be controlled by the parent component, and it should pass toggle functions in.  If I'm not, I'd recommend starting a new question so you can provide more details (than will fit in a comment).

Comment: I created a new thread with a working example of my problem.  I should have done this to start with, but felt guilty posting two questions in one day.  [Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41411694/reactjs-callback-issues-on-setstate)